# How can I pass URI/URL to Android media player?

Tags: android, url, uri, android-mediaplayer, media

Not talking about MediaPlayer, but about the app that comes bundled with Advent Vega tablet (2.2).

How can I pass a URI/URL to a media player app from my own code?

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee it will work but you could try something like this...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
Uri data = Uri.parse("http://someserver.com/thefile.mp3"); 
intent.setDataAndType(data,"audio/mp3"); 
try { 
    startActivity(intent); 
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```